# Corona sdk not view random text

Tags: text, random, lua, coronasdk

I'm have a problem because when I touch my button sometimes my text doe not appear and I do not understand what is wrong.

Code:

```
function randomText(event)
    display.remove(mmDis)
    local a = {"Cristiano ronaldo jest najlepszy!",
               "messi jest dobry!","lewandowski jest ok","diego lopez to bramkarz realu"}

    com = (a[math.random(1,#a)])


    local mmDis = display.newText(tostring(com), 
        display.contentWidth*0.57, display.contentHeight*0.7,               
        display.contentWidth*0.9, display.contentHeight*0.8, "Impact", 30)
        mmDis.y=20
        mmDis.x=190
        mmDis:setFillColor(0, 0, 0, 1)  
        mmDis.anchorY = 0    
end 

play:addEventListener ("tap", randomText )

    end

 end
play:addEventListener( "touch", object )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To help you get answers I have formatted your code properly using the code format button and added tags that will help the experts find your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fully understand the **display.newText** api of Corona SDK you can view it here: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newText.html

For the **Tap event** you can view it here: 
https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/tap/index.html

But I have fixed your code for you. But I really can't understand why you have **"Impact"** there. but here is a working code you can try:

```
local mmDis
local play
local com

function randomText(event)

    if (event.numTaps == 1) then

        display.remove(mmDis)
        print("called")
        local a = {"Cristiano ronaldo jest najlepszy!",
                   "messi jest dobry!","lewandowski jest ok","diego lopez to bramkarz realu"}

        com = (a[math.random(1,#a)])


        mmDis = display.newText(tostring(com),0,0, native.systemFont, 9 )
        mmDis.x = display.contentWidth/2 
        mmDis.y = display.contentHeight/2 + 50

        print(com)
    end
end 

    play = display.newImageRect("images/bg_btn_play.png", 102, 48) -- THIS IS MY BUTTON (CHANGE THIS TO YOUR BUTTON)
    play.x = display.contentWidth/2
    play.y = display.contentHeight/2


play:addEventListener ("tap", randomText )
```

Happy Coding and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Goodluck mate!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 local mmDis 
 local play 
 local com

    local a = {"Cristiano ronaldo jest najlepszy!",
               "messi jest dobry!","lewandowski jest ok","diego lopez to bramkarz realu"}  

    mmDis = display.newText("",0,0, native.systemFont, 9 )
    mmDis.x = display.contentWidth/2 
    mmDis.y = display.contentHeight/2 + 5

play = display.newImageRect("images/bg_btn_play.png", 102, 48) 
play.x = display.contentWidth/2
play.y = display.contentHeight/2 function randomText(event)
local function randomText (event)
  if event.phase == "ended" then
    if (event.numTaps == 1) then
      com = math.random(1,#a)
      print(com)
      mmDis.text = a[com]
    end
  return true
end    
play:addEventListener ("touch", randomText )
```